# Best way to dynamically store and access data in Swift

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, jsondecoder

I have an app where every time it starts up (within the splash screen) it gets the currently logged in users' data from my database via an API endpoint.
The type of JSON expected to be sent back to the app when it asks for data is as shown:

```
{
"username": "test",
"email": "test@gmail.com",
"uid": "5f661ffe1a80160027a6cb0c",
"isVerified": true,
"hub": {
    "hubID": "npnDsZegiSL5",
    "isSetup": true,
    "hubSWVersion": 0.11,
    "_id": "5f661ffe1a80160027a6cb0d",
    "cameraService": {
        "isSetup": true,
        "bridgeIP": "192.168.0.12",
        "username": "JesCGSr6HrWoKbKnnNOHSayVKdb1"
    },
    "servicesSetup": {
        "1": "cameraService",
        "2": "TPLinkPlug"
    }
},
    "code": "100",
    "message": "Success. User details have been provided"
}
```

As the user adds services/updates values, this database structure will constantly change. Which is my problem. There are tonnes of questions like this out there with all the same answer, to use the `JSONDecoder` and push the values to an observable object which can be accessed throughout the app via creating an instance of it or just to simply assign the values to the object when it has been fetched. Which I have done and am currently using:

The class `userData` object:

```
class userData: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    var userdata = userData.self
    @Published var uid: String = ""
    @Published var isVerified: Bool = false
    @Published var username: String = ""
    @Published var email: String = ""
}
```

The code where I assign the values to the object when I receive the above json in my app:

```
...
@EnvironmentObject var user: userData
print("Successfully got user data. Code: \(code ?? "0"). UID: \(response?["uid"] as! String). Username: \(response?["username"] as! String)")
DispatchQueue.main.async {
user.email = response?["email"] as! String
user.uid = response?["uid"] as! String
user.username = response?["username"] as! String
...
```

Then I can access it anywhere in my via:

```
@EnvironmentObject var user: userData
username = self.user.username
```

But this would require hard-coded code to assign each value from my database, is there a better, more dynamic way to assign the whole json response from my API (no matter what values/embedded jsons there is) to an object and access these data values throughout my app via that object?

Thanks

Comment: you can store the response as a `Dictionary` and iterate over the keys instead of having hardcoded fields.

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani If you think that would be the best way, could you add to this comment with example code as an answer so this question can help others, including me?

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani And how would I be able to access said dictionary from anywhere within the app?

Comment: It depends on your architecture. for example, you can pass that dictionary as `EnvironmentObject`. or store that in your database, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you'll have new key value pairs in your response, I think you should store the response as a `Dictionary` and get desired values from that dictionary instead of parsing the response and storing separate variables.
here is an example:

```
    let jsonStr = """
        {\"username\": \"test\",
        \"email\": \"test@gmail.com\",
        \"uid\": \"5f661ffe1a80160027a6cb0c\",
        \"isVerified\": true,
        \"hub\": {
            \"hubID\": \"npnDsZegiSL5\",
            \"isSetup\": true,
            \"hubSWVersion\": 0.11,
            \"_id\": \"5f661ffe1a80160027a6cb0d\",
            \"cameraService\": {
                \"isSetup\": true,
                \"bridgeIP\": \"192.168.0.12\",
                \"username\": \"JesCGSr6HrWoKbKnnNOHSayVKdb1\"
            },
            \"servicesSetup\": {
                \"1\": \"cameraService\",
                \"2\": \"TPLinkPlug\"
            }
        },
            \"code\": \"100\",
            \"message\": \"Success. User details have been provided\"
        }
    """
    
    let data = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8)
    
    do {
        // store this variable
        let dict =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        
        for (k,v) in dict! {
            // example access to values
            print("key: \(k), value: \(v)")
        }
        
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: You are using `jsonStr` to pass into the `JSONSerialization` function. I have a json object that is returned from my API. If I pass that json object instead (`try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json!, options: [])` I get the error: `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` I'd either need to make the json object returned the same format as yours above or use a different function?

Comment: I assumed that you get the response as `String`.

Comment: It works, I had already done that before hand, just that I cannot get the values that are embedded into that json, e.g. the values in `hub`

Comment: as the `hub` value is a `Dictionary` itself, you should cast it to a `Dictionary` to access the values in it.
example:
let hubDict = dict["hub"] as! Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>